# why is my java program printing "null" in output for a string when I took it as an input through a method?

Tags: java, input, null

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

class fields{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fn;
    String ln;
    String em;
    String phn;
    String country;
    String city;
    public fields() {
        System.out.println("\n                    ~~~ FORM ~~~\n");
        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        input(fn);
        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        input(ln);
        System.out.print("Email: ");
        input(em);
        System.out.print("Phone number: ");
        input(phn);
        System.out.print("Country: ");
        input(country);
        System.out.print("City: ");

        input(city);
    }
    public void input(String x){
        x = sc.nextLine();
    }
    public void output(){
        System.out.println("The user's name is: " + fn + " " + ln + "\nEmail: " + em + "\nPhone Number: " + phn + ",\nand lives in: " + city + ", " + country);
    }
}

public class Form {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fields obj = new fields();
        System.out.println("\n                    ~~~ OUTPUT ~~~\n");
        obj.output();

    }
}
```

I am new to java. and I am still learning its concepts. I think it might be a problem of scopes of variable initialization. I am looking forward to being guided by anyone who can solve my problem. Thankyou

Comment: String is an object and is immutable.  So when assign new values, it creates new object in memory. So the `String x` holds the reference of what you are passing(i.e, `fn`) which refers to null but when `x = sc.nextLine();`, it creates a new object(string from input) in memory  and `x` now refers to that. `fn` still refers null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the input() method. This method receives a String parameter. But remember that parameters in java are passed by value and in particular Strings are immutable objects so when you invoke input() and pass a String variable as a parameter, this variable is copied. So the value you are modifying inside the input() method is the copy of the parameter sent. That's why the fn, ln, em, phn, country, city variables are never initialized.

An alternative implementation of input method is the following:

```java
public String input(){
    return sc.nextLine();
}
```

And invoke it as the following example:

```java
:
System.out.print("Last Name: ");
ln = input();
:
```

This is just a playful example to understand how parameters are passed in java because using a method just to execute the read from de standard input seems to be unnecessary.

A final comment: As a convention, Class names in java start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

The null values are coming from `input` method which dosen't initialize values, one of the correct form will be like below

```
public class Fields {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private String fn;
private String ln;
private String em;
private String phn;
private String country;
private String city;

public Fields() {
    System.out.println("\n                    ~~~ FORM ~~~\n");
    System.out.print("First Name: ");
    this.fn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    this.ln = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Email: ");
    this.em = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Phone number: ");
    this.phn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Country: ");
    this.country = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("City: ");
    this.city = sc.nextLine();
}

public void output() {
    System.out.println("The user's name is: " + fn + " " +
            ln + "\nEmail: " + em + "\nPhone Number: " + phn + ",\nand lives in: " + city + ", " + country);
}}
```

More over please respect language [conventions][1] for class naming .

[1]: [https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#:~:text=Class%20names%20should%20be%20nouns,such%20as%20URL%20or%20HTML](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#:%7E:text=Class%20names%20should%20be%20nouns,such%20as%20URL%20or%20HTML)).